# Specify alternative patterns to grep

Tags: cron, grep

I am looking for tailing 2 command strings that are triggered from crontab scheduler and should be visible from `/var/log/syslog`. This to verify that the scheduled job is really executed.

My lines in crontab looks like this:

```
*/1 6-23 * * 1-7 sleep 50; cd /tmp2 && /usr/bin/Rscript run1.R

*/1 6-23 * * 1-7 sleep 50; cd /tmp2 && /usr/bin/Rscript run2.R
```

This works:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep run1.R
```

This does not work:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep run1.R && run2.R
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep run1.R && run2.R
```

will run

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep run1.R
```

and when and if that exits successfully, it will (try to) run

```
run2.R
```

afterwards because of the `&&` in-between. I assume you want one of

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep -F -e run1.R -e run2.R
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep -E "run[12]\.R"
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep -E "run1\.R|run2\.R"
```

to filter the lines that contain either `run1.R` or `run2.R` (or both).

Note that `tail -f /var/log/syslog` usually never exits as long as the given
file exists -- which should be the case for that particular file.